# It's safe to keep the node_modules directory when building prod war?

Tags: jhipster

In other words, why does the prod profile in pom.xml need to clean the node_modules directory?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is safe and this is no longer the case in 3.1.0